# How to integrate CCAvenue Payment Gateway in my website

Tags: codeigniter, payment-gateway

I want to integrate CCAvenue Payment gateway in my site, but I am getting this error in "Integration Kit" provided by CCavnue.

> Error Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the URL/Referral URl is same as the one you have registered with the CCAvenue Merchant account.

Also the working Key, Access Code should be same as the one you get it from your account API Keys(Settings link)

Do not use the localhost url for the testing which will result in the Error COde: 10002.

If everything is correct and still you are receiving this error. Please contact the CCAvenue by raising the support ticket in their Helpdesk.

They will do some configuration changes in your account and the issue will be rectified.

Hope this helps!!

Cheers,
Raj

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to test the CCAvenue on localhost.

Just change your host file and add approved website URL like below:

> 127.0.0.1    approvedSiteURL.com

change approvedSiteURL.com with your live site URL approved from CCAvenue.

In case of windows you can find the file at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. Search for other operating systems.

Now when you type approvedSiteURL.com on your browser, it will show as you run localhost. Hence you can run the CCAvenue on localhost without 10002 error and without putting files on live server.

Note:  approvedSiteURL.com is your approved live site URL here. Replace it with your site url.

Comment: Did you changed the host file? It should work. It is still working at my end.